# mpdf 8.0 - custom font not loaded

Tags: php, css, fonts, mpdf

I´m trying to add a font in my pdf thanks the php mpdf library.
[As the version 7.x, the version 8.x seems to work exactly at the same way](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/discussions/1559).

This my code :

### index.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
  'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
    __DIR__ . '/font',
  ]),
  'fontdata' => $fontData + [
      'Work Sans' => [
        'R' => 'WorkSans-Regular.ttf',
        'I' => 'WorkSans-Italic.ttf',
      ]
    ]
]);
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/pdf.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$html = file_get_contents('./html/pdf.html');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

### pdf.css

```
#doc {
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

It does not work.That applies `sans-serif` instead. Someone has got an idea ?

Comment: The example says the font name must be lower-case: https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html